# Modificar el tamaño del CollapsingToolbarLayout

Tags: android

Quiero modificar el tamaño de el `CollapsingToolbarLayout` para que no exista tanto espacio entre los tres puntos de menu y la barra principal.

Esto es lo que tengo:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y lo que deseo es "eliminar" o disminuir la barra de color rosa (colorAccent) omo en la siguiente imagen:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es el código del `Layout`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
 tools:context="recyclerview.ejemplo.aldakur.net.ejemplorecyclerview.MainActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/parallax_collapsing"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
            app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
            android:background="@color/colorAccent">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/parallax_image"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                android:src="@drawable/images"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"/>

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/parallax_toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:background="@android:color/transparent"

                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"

                app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
                android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />
        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <!--<include layout="@layout/content_main" />-->

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/parallax_rv"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

    </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/parallax_fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

**Edito:** En Android 4.1 se visualiza correctamente, pero no en Android 6.0

Comment: No ser si lo entiendo, quieres eliminar la parte rosa que es el tamaño que tiene la statusbar y que la imagen se visualice por debajo de ella, mostrando la actionbar por encima de todo?

Comment: Si te fijas mi `statusbar` rosa es mas grande que de lo normal. Si te fijas la distancia que tengo yo desde los tres puntitos del menu hacia arriba es mayor que lo norma.

Comment: A parte que el ojo humano con determinadas formas combinación de colores, la percepción que sea diferente es normal a simple vista, pero si lo compruebas pixel a pixel te darás cuenta que es el mismo tamaño.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Viendo que el espacio del color rosa es igual a la altura de la statusbar.

Para realizar que los elementos se dibujen por debajo de la `StatusBar` debes asignar a los que quieras la propiedad `android:fitsSystemWindows="true"`

Para que `fitSystemWindows` tenga efecto antes debes asignar al tema de la actividad `values-21/styles.xml` lo siguiente:

```
<item name="android:windowDrawsSystemBarBackgrounds">true</item>
<item name="android:statusBarColor">@android:color/transparent</item>
```

**Update**

El `wrap_content` no funciona del todo bien en las imágenes dentro del `CollapsingToolbarLayout`

La imágenes si no se especifica lo contrario android las visualiza de forma que quepan dentro del view, yo para ajustarlas utilizo la librería `glide` o bien por código defino el height de la `AppBarLayout`

Tu código en `AppBarLayout` defines `200dp` de altura, donde tienes `wrap_content` pon `match_parent` y añade `android:fitsSystemWindows="true"` a todos los elementos que quieras que parten den top absoluto.

Prueba ese código:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context="recyclerview.ejemplo.aldakur.net.ejemplorecyclerview.MainActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/parallax_collapsing"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
            app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            android:background="@color/colorAccent">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/parallax_image"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                android:src="@drawable/images"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"/>

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/parallax_toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:background="@android:color/transparent"

                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"

                app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
                android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />
        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <!--<include layout="@layout/content_main" />-->

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/parallax_rv"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

    </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/parallax_fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: He editado la pregunta. En la pregunta no había apuesto el código correspondiente a `CoordinatorLayout` en cual tiene la linean `android:fitsSystemWindows="true"`pero el problema presiste.

Comment: Sí. Se me duplico. Lo he corregido en la pregunta. Siguiendo tus indicaciones todo es correcto. Gracias!

Answer (score 0):

Tu implementación del `CollapsingToolbarLayout` es correcto, mas bien creo que tu imagen es menor al tamaño del `AppBarLayout` que es de `200dp`, y es por eso que se muestra el color de `background` o `contentScrim` configurados en tu `CollapsingToolbarLayout`

Comment: Las dimensiones de la imagen son de 800 x 600 en jpg